# Query Not returning exactly what I want

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm a little confused to why my query is not returning exactly what I expect. This is my query in SQL.

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"alerts\" ON \"alerts\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE (bus_route = 'The 06:30 To Wexford' AND stop = 'Camolin' AND first_alert = '5' OR second_alert = '5' OR third_alert = '5')"
```

And this is what I have in Rails:

```
Alert.where("bus_route = '#{b}' AND stop = '#{s}' AND first_alert = '#{t}' OR second_alert = '#{t}' OR third_alert = '#{t}'")
```

The conditions I am aiming for here is to find an alert with the bus_route passed, stop passed and either the first, second or third alert can equal the time in minutes passed.

But what my query is doing is returning is an alert where as long as any of the alert fields equal the parameter passed and the bus_route and stop do not equal.

I am a big SQL and Rails query noob for the record and this is my first "complex" query.

Help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parentheses around the `first_alert = '#{t}' OR second_alert = '#{t}' OR third_alert = '#{t}'` section, OR has a lower priority than AND.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to enclose the OR statements in a parenthesis

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"alerts\" ON \"alerts\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE ((bus_route = 'The 06:30 To Wexford' AND stop = 'Camolin') AND (first_alert = '5' OR second_alert = '5' OR third_alert = '5'))"
```